# Concatenating dictionaries of numpy arrays (avoiding manual loops if possible)

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy

I am looking for a way to concatenate the values in two python dictionaries that contain numpy arrays whilst avoiding having to manually loop over the dictionary keys. For example:

```
import numpy as np

# Create first dictionary
n = 5
s = np.random.randint(1,101,n)
r = np.random.rand(n)
d = {"r":r,"s":s}
print "d = ",d

# Create second dictionary
n = 2
s = np.random.randint(1,101,n)
r = np.random.rand(n)
t = np.array(["a","b"])
d2 = {"r":r,"s":s,"t":t}
print "d2 = ",d2

# Some operation to combine the two dictionaries...
d = SomeOperation(d,d2)

# Updated dictionary
print "d3 = ",d
```

to give the output

```
>> d =  {'s': array([75, 25, 88, 54, 82]), 'r': array([ 0.1021227 ,  0.99454874, 0.38680718,  0.98720877,  0.8662894 ])}
>> d2 =  {'s': array([78, 92]), 'r': array([ 0.27610587,  0.57037473]), 't': array(['a', 'b'], dtype='|S1')}
>> d3 =  {'s': array([75, 25, 88, 54, 82, 78, 92]), 'r': array([ 0.1021227 ,  0.99454874, 0.38680718,  0.98720877,  0.8662894, 0.27610587,  0.57037473]), 't': array(['a', 'b'], dtype='|S1')}
```

i.e. so that if the key already exists, the numpy array stored under that key is appended to.

Does anybody know the best way to do this, whilst minimising the use of slow, manual `for` loops? (I would like to avoid loops because the dictionaries I would like to combine could have hundreds of keys).

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen something similar using `defaultdict` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), but this still involves manually looping over the keys of the second dictionary. Is there a smarter, more efficient way to achieve the same result?

Comment: @aim is it really NECESSARY to put the arrays inside dicts in the first place?

Comment: @heltonbiker: the data in each of the dictionaries is columns of data from an ascii file, where the keys of the dictionary correspond to the column headings. I load the information into dictionaries so that I do not need to know the number of columns in the file beforehand. By reading each file into a dictionary and then updating that dictionary, I can read in a series of files with the same format. Typically I have to read in simulation data where the simulation has been split into 512 files, where each file corresponds to a small spatial volume of the simulation box.

Comment: @heltonbiker: I have been using dictionaries because I believed them to be the most flexible tool to achieve what I wanted. Do you know of a more efficient and/or more flexible tool/method for reading large numbers of ascii files?

Comment: Well, it of course depends, but the way your question is stated makes me think that you would like vectorized, numpy-like fast array operations WITHOUT iteration, and I believe this is a bit more than a plain old dictionary can provide, but maybe someone else knows some trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pandas for that:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create first dictionary
n = 5
s = np.random.randint(1,101,n)
r = np.random.rand(n)
d = {"r":r,"s":s}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

# Create second dictionary
n = 2
s = np.random.randint(1,101,n)
r = np.random.rand(n)
t = np.array(["a","b"])
d2 = {"r":r,"s":s,"t":t}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
print(df2)

print(pd.concat([df, df2]))
```

Outputs:

```
          r   s
0  0.551402  49
1  0.620870  34
2  0.535525  52
3  0.920922  13
4  0.708109  48
          r   s  t
0  0.231480  43  a
1  0.492576  10  b
          r   s    t
0  0.551402  49  NaN
1  0.620870  34  NaN
2  0.535525  52  NaN
3  0.920922  13  NaN
4  0.708109  48  NaN
0  0.231480  43    a
1  0.492576  10    b
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Pandas is DESIGNED to apply this kind of operation to very very large datasets in the fastest possible way. In this case I'd go for it! +1 for sample code!

Comment: @heltonbiker as long as the dataset fits into RAM.

Comment: I believe some combinations of Pandas / PyTables / HDF5 can abstract disk-based data access, although the last time I took a look it looked to require a bit of work to get going...